# How can I dispose a view when navigating away with Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, castle-windsor, prism-6

I'm experimenting with Prism and have created a simple application consisting of a main window with a Prism region, along with two "child" views (and VMs). Each of these child views has a button, and clicking this simply navigates to the other view, e.g.:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainWindowRegion", "HomeView");
```

The child views and view models implement `IDisposable`, and have been given a "Transient" lifetime in my DI container. Additionally the views implement `IRegionMemberLifetime` (KeepAlive = false).

Despite all this, the views aren't getting disposed (until I close the application). What am I missing? How do I dispose of a view when I navigate away from it?

Or would it be simpler to register the child views as singletons and initialise them whenever I navigate to them?

Comment: If I understand correctly your real problem is that when you navigate to another view, the old view still takes the memory? Have you tried to just call GC.Collect()?

Comment: @jannagy02 I've just tried this (after the calls to `RequestNavigate()`) but it still doesn't result in the views being disposed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting your IDisposable methods to fire and that is what you are using to determine if your views are being "disposed" then you're doing it wrong. That's not how it works.  The GC will do its job when it is ready. If you are using IRegionMemberLifetime then you are doing what you need to in order to remove the view from the region and have it available for GC.  You'll want to do some research on IDisposable and how it works in WPF.

Comment: Yeah I guess I was expecting Dispose() to get called fairly soon after navigating away. I've been doing this job long enough so should know better by now that the GC doesn't work like that.

Comment: Yeah, that damn GC is annoying to work with especially in WPF.  As long as you implement IRegionMemberLifetime, the views are removed form the region and ready for collection. You can verify by checking the region manager. Don't worry, you're doing it right.

Comment: I'm using Castle Windsor, and my only concern is that perhaps something somewhere isn't wired up to release the views. As mentioned in an earlier comment, I've tried calling `GC.Collect()` but I'm still not seeing the Dispose() methods being called - but that could again be down to my poor understanding of GC.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Castle Windsor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the IDestructible from Prism.Navigation to your viewmodel, as described in the bottom of this article:

https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/creating-your-first-prism-app.html

This will call the `public void Destroy()` in your viewmodel when the user navigates away.